# Realizar CURL de forma directa

Tags: php, api

Tengo esta info de conexión a una API de traducción:

```
curl https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate \
-d auth_key = tu_auth_key \
-d "texto = Esta es la primera oración". \
-d "texto = Esta es la segunda oración". \
-d "texto = Esta es la tercera oración". \
-d "target_lang = DE"
```

Y el siguiente código PHP que hace la llamada a la API para traducir un texto:

```
// CONFIGURAMOS API DE TRADUCCION
$apiurl = "https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate";
$apikey = XXXX;
$texto = $ contenido;
$target_lang = "DE";
$url = $ apiurl. "? auth_key =". $ apikey. "& text =". urlencode ($ titulo). "& text =". urlencode ($ text). "& target_lang =". $ target_lang;
$ch = curl_init ($ url);
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resultado = curl_exec ($ ch);
```

Este código funciona perfectamente con textos no muy largos pero falla cuando se mandan textos largos, desde el soporte de la API me dicen que es porque tengo que hacer una llamada directa CURL ¿cómo puedo hacer esto con PHP?

Comment: No creo que la solución a esto sea *hacerlo de forma directa*. Es normal que una API tenga limitaciones con respecto al tamaño del contenido que se le envía (lo tiene incluso el traductor de Google), es que si no, imagínate que la API admita un capítulo entero o un libro y varias decenas o miles de usuarios mandando contenido indiscriminado. Te recomendaría informarte sobre la cantidad máxima de caracteres admitidos por la API y dividir tu contenido en paquetes no mayores a esa cantidad. Esa sería la solución óptima.

Comment: [Aquí te lo dice claramente](https://www.deepl.com/es/docs-api/accessing-the-api/limits/): *The request body size should not exceed 128 KiB (128 * 1024 bytes).* En ningún caso te admitirá una petición con un body de tamaño superior a 128Kb. Y, si es un error 414 el que tienes (URL demasiado larga), te proponen una petición POST en vez de GET, de modo que puedas enviar los parámetros en el body: *Error 414: The request URL is too long. You can avoid this error by using a POST request instead of a GET request, and sending the parameters in the HTTP body.*

Comment: @A.Cedano como puedo hacer una petición POST con CURL enviando los parámetros en el HTTP body?¿

Comment: En la [primera nota de contribución del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/curl.examples-basic.php#117009) tienes un ejemplo. Debes setear `CURLOPT_POST => true` simplemente y ya cURL entiende que quieres una petición POST. Por supuesto debes pasar los datos, la API KEY y todo lo demás, pero **NO en la URL** sino crear un array y pasarlo en `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. La diferencia es que al ser una petición POST los datos viajarán en el body y no deberá haber problema si no exceden el máximo permitido. Sea como sea, te aconsejo que captures los errores de tu petición cURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La API con la que estás trabajando te dice claramente que:

> The request body size should not exceed 128 KiB (128 * 1024 bytes).

Es decir, que en ningún caso te admitirá una petición con un body de tamaño superior a 128Kb. Si tal es el caso, debes separar tu contenido en fragmentos no mayores de 128Kb e irlos pesando a la API para la traducción.

Por el contrario, si es un error 414 el que tienes (URL demasiado larga), la API te propone una petición POST en vez de GET, de modo que puedas enviar los parámetros en el body:

> Error 414: The request URL is too long. You can avoid this error by
> using a POST request instead of a GET request, and sending the
> parameters in the HTTP body.

Aquí te muestro cómo hacer una petición POST con cURL. Además, convendría que captures los errores:

```
$apiurl = "https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate";
$apikey = XXXX;
$texto = $contenido;
$target_lang = "DE";
$params=['auth_key'=>$apikey, 'text'=>$texto, 'target_lang'=>$target_lang];
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $apiurl,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$resultado = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    #Usar aquí $resultado
    var_dump($resultado);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

#### PD:

Hay algo confuso en tu código original, y es que la URL tiene dos veces un parámetro `text` ¿?

Comment: He modificado un poco tu código para que funcionase, he editado tu respuesta para que quede ahí el código validado. Gracias por todo, me pusiste en la pista correcta!

Comment: Por cierto mi código original tiene dos parámetros text porque uno es el titulo del post a traducir y el otro el contenido, para así mantenerlo y luego volcarlo a WP.

Comment: @NandoMerino la URL ya se pasa en los option: `CURLOPT_URL => $apiurl,` no hace falta ponerla cuando inicias cURL.

Comment: Cuando lo tenía como tu me indicabas me daba error de CURL de not set url por eso lo puse cuando se inicia CURL

Comment: @NandoMerino eso ocurría porque había dos llamadas a `curl_init()` una antes y otra después de setear los option. Corrige por favor ese error en tu código final y puedes dejar la URL en el array o setearla al llamar a `curl_init()`, cualquiera de las dos es válida, si no lo haces desde el array entonces quita esa opción para no tener redundancia. Yo prefiero configurar todo en el array, porque el código queda más claro así pero eso ya es cuestión de estilos. También he corregido un error que había en `$params`, terminaba con `)`  cuando debía terminar con `]`. Saludos.

Comment: Genial, ya veo que has dejado el código perfecto, yo he hecho lo mismo. Gracias!