# ¿Por qué no puedo hacer una petición POST con CURL - PHP que sí se puede con POSTMAN?

Tags: php, php7, curl, postman

Quiero iniciar sesión automáticamente en un sitio web, para ello me conecto al dominio base, ejemplo, [www.base.com](http://www.base.com) y obtengo un token de autenticación que está en el HTML, acto seguido hago un request con usuario, contraseña, utf8 y el token obtenido anteriormente.

Si hago este request con POSTMAN u otro programa funciona, pero si lo intento con CURL POST no funciona ¿por qué? he intentado con varios códigos, incluso el propio que genera postman para curl-php.

**El código generado por POSTMAN es el siguiente:**

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.sitioweb.com/jr3/sessions?user=BLABLA&password=blablabla&authenticity_token=oQA5vffdfWHPPB2aLOtZl8ujAi7/fKa2orwH9Gfnd4=&utf8=%25E2%259C%2593',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: ROUTEID=.2; _jr3_session=ecd1960218b187de6d63f292a0ef8de8'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Lo único que he hecho en POSTMAN ha sido indicar:

- Método: POST
- URL
- Parámetros y valores: utf8, user, password, authenticity_token y me muestro como resultado el logeo realizado satisfactoriamente.

¿Alguna explicación lógica para esto? Adicionalmente, me gustaría decir que también he generado el código CURL para consola y tampoco funciona, me estoy volviendo loco.

Edición:

He probado lo que me han sugerido en los comentarios y tampoco funciona.

He añadido este código dentro del array de opciones.

```
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'user=miuser',
    'password=mipass',
    'utf8=%25E2%259C%2593',
    'authenticity_token=3s3QIt3/i8qKqU8tZD7sjaKfGY575ZHfcag/ktJQ0aRPq1jbfzRknhUzOWqQ8r6CoTGvbYvHWbIP2Flndsad==',
  ),
```

Comment: Estás enviando los campos por URL, que es para peticiones GET. Debes incluirlos en el arreglo con `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [user => 'Usuario', password => 'contraseña']`. Para más información, revisa la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: créeme que eso lo intenté y tampoco funciona.

Comment: Acabo de intentarlo de nuevo, no funciona. He editado mi pregunta y he agregado el code.

Comment: Es probable que solo usuario y contraseña deban ir como campos, no sé si alguno de los otros dos (o ambos) tengan que ir como encabezados.

Comment: Establece un control de errores, imprime el mensaje de error que está arrojando tu petición cURL y agrégalo a la pregunta. Debes entender que no conviene programar de una manera ingenua. Tu petición falla y te preguntas por qué falla ... Tu tarea como programador es prever ese fallo y controlarlo. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cURL con control de errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/490284/29967), es muy simple. Controla tu código y dinos cuál es el error, quizá al verlo sabrás lo que ocurre y podrás resolverlo.