# cURL - PHP no funciona

Tags: php, curl

Estoy intentando hacer un cURL desde php para una pagina y funciona correctamente solo en el servidor localhost cuando subo el código a producción desde cualquiera de los servidores que tengo todos me devuelven false como si la pagina web estuviese caída. Me causa curiosidad que en el servidor localhost si funcione correctamente.

Anteriormente servia el código pero desde hace algunos días no funciona.

el código es el siguen.

```
$ch=curl_init("http://www.fise.gob.pe/programa-nuevos-suministros-gnr-financiamiento.html");
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
        CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'gzip, deflate',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
                'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
                'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                'Connection: keep-alive',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
        ),
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo darle una mirada a tu configuración PHP en el hosting. Crea un `phpinfo();` y fijate si tenes habilitado `cURL support enabled`

Comment: Intenta recoger el error de tu petición cURL y dinos si muestra algo, puede ser un problema del sitio remoto, de autentificación, etc. Si no sabes cómo controlar los errores, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/490284/29967). Se trata simplemente de verificar con algo como: `if(curl_errno($ch)) { var_dump(curl_error($ch)); } else  { // Aquí usar los datos que trajo cURL }`

Comment: Esa web tiene el servidor caido, o eso parece, no responde al navegador, ni al ping, ni al wget, ni al telnet 80, al menos desde un par de IPs españolas.  Supongo que debes esperarte a que lo arreglen. A menos que se hayan vuelto paranoicos y hayan bloqueado por paises o restrigindo su acceso a determinadas ips o rangos, que tambien podria ser si tu dices que desde tu localhost te funciona.

Comment: masterguru creo que con lo que me dijiste el problema es de bloqueo de ip o algo así porque desde los servidores no puedo acceder obviamente porque tienen una ip fuera del país y desde mi pc si puedo...

Comment: Acabo de volver a probar y sigue igual, por lo tanto me parece que si, que tengo cierta razón, y por los motivos que sean se han dedicado a bloquear ips, entre ellas las españolas a las que tengo acceso (un par de ellas), y seguramente la que tambien dices tu desde tu servidor extranjero.  Es una mala práctica, pero ellos sabran porque lo hacen.  Lo unico que se me ocurre es que desde tu servidor hagas la conexion via proxy con IP de tu pais y a ver si hay suerte.